# VBA how to enable a Click Event in a subform?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a Subform, which shows the results of a search, using Data of many searchboxes. I'd like to use a subform instead of a ListBox, because so the user can use the OrderBy and filters. Now I want that the user can doubleclick a field, and receive the first value of this row.

```
Me.SearchResultForm.Form.RecordSource = query  'query contains the precalculated sql query
Me.SearchResultForm.Requery
```

This works really well.

```
Me.SearchResultForm.Form.OnDblClick = onResultDblClick   '--> a function
```

This does something strange: It fires once at requery, but NOT at doubleclick...

How can I get this working? Or is there a better solution?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
Me.SearchResultForm.Form.OnDblClick = "=onResultDblClick()"   '--> a function
```

As noted on msdn [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195867%28v=office.11%29.aspx), when setting an Event Property, you assign it a string that is either a Macro, an Event Procedure or a User Defined Function.